# Spark, String to Timestamp

Tags: scala, apache-spark, time, timestamp

I've got the next `String` column:

```
+-------------------+
|          Data_Time|
+-------------------+
|22.07.2017 10:06:51|
|22.07.2017 10:06:51|
|22.07.2017 10:06:51|
|22.07.2017 10:03:45|
|22.07.2017 10:03:45|
+-------------------+
```

I want to convert it to `Timestamp`.

I'm trying to do with:

```scala
val dfSorted = df.withColumn("Data_Time_Pattern", to_timestamp(col("Data_Time"), "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
```

But I'm getting `null` values:

```
+-------------------+-----------------+
|          Data_Time|Data_Time_Pattern|
+-------------------+-----------------+
|22.07.2017 10:06:51|             null|
|22.07.2017 10:06:51|             null|
|22.07.2017 10:06:51|             null|
|22.07.2017 10:03:45|             null|
|22.07.2017 10:03:45|             null|
+-------------------+-----------------+
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: works for me, error is not reproducible

Comment: very strange =( https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNie2.png

Comment: Are you sure you're getting null-values? Can you show the line of code that is trying to display the new dataFrames? I know spark often is lazy-loaded, so things won't be displayed properly.. could it be something like this? Anyhow, add how you are trying to display it and the result

Comment: Ah, I see now you posted it. So I guess it's probably not that then. What I think it could be would be, either the dateformatting breaks or you're somehow selection it wrong. But since mck tried to reproduce it without success, I guess it must be something just on your end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.I had "\t" as the separator, and changing the value to " " made it work.